# Need clarification about Protobuf-net RuntimeTypeModel

Tags: protobuf-net

I am using Protobuf-net with DataContracts. I register types this way:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeA].AddSubType(fieldNumber, typeB);
```

The problem is that `fieldNumber` is explicitly restricted inside protobuf-net code to accept integers which are `> 0` and `< Int32.Max/4`.

```
internal static void WriteHeaderCore(int fieldNumber, WireType wireType, ProtoWriter writer)
        {
            uint header = (((uint)fieldNumber) << 3)
                | (((uint)wireType) & 7);
            WriteUInt32Variant(header, writer);
        }
```

[Line 185](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/protobuf-net/ProtoWriter.cs)

What was the reason doing it this way? Backward compatibility? CrossPlatform compatibility? Possible bug?

UPDATE to show how I use DataContracts

```
    // this guid is transformed to integer and it is a special one so brotobuf-net does not blow up.
    // That way I can safely rename the class whenever I want. Same for properies.
    [DataContract(Name = "c8978654-4380-44d2-8ebe-ae17a463dfb6")] 
    public class UserState 
    {
        UserState() { }

        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public override UserId Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public string Firstname { get; private set; }

    }
```

Comment: Why is it a problem though?

Comment: I use Guid as a name in DataContract attribute. Then the type is registered with someGuid.GetHashCode() as fieldNumber. I know that this does not provide me uniqueness but it is acceptable. The problem is that now I have to use specially crafted Guids like I am doing it right now.

Comment: @myknow Using a random Guid is not efficient anyways, as the field numbers themselves are also stored as varint, and would take up more bytes for arbitrary numbers (if efficiency is even an issue here).

Comment: @Rotem: The guid is transformed to an integer. I will update the question with an example so you can see how I use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is per the [protobuf spec](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto)

> The smallest tag number you can specify is 1, and the largest is 2^29 - 1, or 536,870,911. You also cannot use the numbers 19000 though 19999